# one loop controlling the repetition or validity of the input

Tags: java

```
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is " + "your name? ");
```

How do I make this a do while loop so that if the user inputs a number instead of a string it will not move on till a letter is put in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop make a boolean value set to true, and make it so the loop continues until you change the boolean to false. Only set the boolean to false when you get valid input.

You will of course have to check if the number is a int or a string, but exactly how you'd go about doing that will depend on if you want there to be no numbers at all in the string or if it's okay as long as there is at least one character. There are a lot of answers around about that so I'd just Google it.